# How to execute a function according to user's input to make a two 3x3 matrices? Program in C to make calculations on matrices

Tags: c, function, matrix, type-conversion, division

I'm trying to make my first program in C today, and I've had some troubles with it. I wanted to make program that can make calculations on 2D matrices, i made it working for most of the part, except evaluating division. I suppose it's because matrices are integers and divisions can be floats. Is there a way to make only division function work with floats instead of whole program? Second, and the most important issue comes with my own put() function. I would like to make this whole program work on two modes, first works with already declared matrices, so we don't have to write them every time, second asks you for input to make new matrices to work with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//-------------------PUT--------------------//
//=================================================//
int put(int i, int k, int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]) {
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            scanf("A|%d:%d|:%d\t", &i, &k, &n);
            tabA[i][k] = n;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            scanf("A|%d:%d|:%d\t", &i, &k, &n);
            tabB[i][k] = n;
        }
    }
    return tabA[i][k] && tabB[i][k];
}
//-------------------SUM-------------------//
//=================================================//
int sum(int i, int k, int tabD[3][3], int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            tabD[i][k] = tabA[i][k] + tabB[i][k];
        }
    }
    return tabD[i][k];
}
//-------------------DIF-------------------//
//=================================================//
int dif(int i, int k, int tabD[3][3], int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            tabD[i][k] = tabA[i][k] - tabB[i][k];
        }
    }
    return tabD[i][k];
}
//-------------------DIV-------------------//
//=================================================//
//TODO: fix div - CONVERT TO FLOAT
int div(int i, int k, int tabD[3][3], int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            tabD[i][k] = tabD[i][k] + tabA[i][k] / tabB[i][k];
        }
    }
    return tabD[i][k];
}
//-------------------MUL-------------------//
//=================================================//
int mul(int i, int j, int k, int tabD[3][3], int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            tabD[i][k] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                tabD[i][k] = tabD[i][k] + tabA[i][k] * tabB[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    return tabD[i][k];
}

//-------------------MAIN-------------------//
//=================================================//
int main() {
    //-------------------//
    int i, j, k;
    int y; printf("1: put,\t0: get\t:..."); scanf("%d", &y);
    int tabA[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3} };
    int tabB[3][3] = { {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6} };
    int tabD[3][3];

    //TODO: fix put
    \*
        if (y == 1) {
            put(int i, int k, int tabA[3][3], int tabB[3][3]);
        }
    */

        int x; printf("1: sum,\t2: dif,\t3: div(In Work),\t4: mul\t:..."); scanf("%d", &x);
    //-------------------//

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            switch (x) {
            case 1: printf("|%d:%d| = %d\t", i, k, sum(i, k, tabD, tabA, tabB));
                break;
            case 2: printf("|%d:%d| = %d\t", i, k, dif(i, k, tabD, tabA, tabB));
                break;
            case 3: printf("|%d:%d| = %d\t", i, k, div(i, k, tabD, tabA, tabB));
                break;
            case 4: printf("|%d:%d| = %d\t", i, k, mul(i, j, k, tabD, tabA, tabB));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
//=================================================//
```

I already tried it to work with if statement, and similary with switch, but couldnt get it going.

Comment: Posted code has many \ that are not needed.  Did you really code them there?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica they were added to code when I published my post. It's my first post so maybe I did something wrong. Gonna fix it in a moment